# Serilog Version Numbers

Tags: serilog

I'm looking at different logging frameworks and it seems like Serilog is quite mature.
I am confused by all the different version numbers.  How do I know what sinks belong to what versions of the core framework?  Why aren't the version numbers standardized?

[image: Confusing Verion Numbers]

Comment: The sinks are intentionally written and versioned separately - they don't need to be in sync with releases of the core. Nuget packages include specs as to what the minimum core reference required, but that in general will be conservative. One thing that's confusing about your list is that you've selected prerelease packages - you'll likely find more clarity if you only do release packages. In conclusion, don't worry about it, it's by design - pick your sinks, then pick relevant versions of each one based on release notes

Answer (score 0):

Serilog core hasn't broken backward binary compatibility since 2.0 in June 2016 (a long time ago, in .NET terms), so **all** maintained sinks work with the latest Serilog core package.

You should just need to pick the latest stable version of Serilog and of each sink you wish to use, and everything will just work.

(Sinks may have other dependencies that overlap and conflict, but this would be unusual to encounter.)